# why password connection are lost?

Tags: airflow

I have to update (re-type and save) my ssh connection password every time I restart airflow. Why is that?

I'm running airflow 1.10.3 in a docker container and I can see that all passwords are stored properly in the postgres database.

```
*** Reading local file: /root/airflow/logs/archive/check_source/2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00/4.log
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,253] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: archive.check_source 2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,267] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: archive.check_source 2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,267] {__init__.py:1353} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,267] {__init__.py:1354} INFO - Starting attempt 4 of 4
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,268] {__init__.py:1355} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,295] {__init__.py:1374} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): check_source> on 2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00
[2019-07-08 01:30:27,296] {base_task_runner.py:119} INFO - Running: [u'airflow', u'run', 'archive', 'check_source', '2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00', u'--job_id', '1321', u'--raw', u'-sd', u'DAGS_FOLDER/archive.py', u'--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpQwBRud']
[2019-07-08 01:30:28,392] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source [2019-07-08 01:30:28,392] {settings.py:182} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, pid=656
[2019-07-08 01:30:28,741] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source [2019-07-08 01:30:28,740] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-07-08 01:30:28,975] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source [2019-07-08 01:30:28,974] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags/archive.py
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,073] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source [2019-07-08 01:30:29,073] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: archive_to_glacier.check_source 2019-07-07T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-webserver-66d5747dc7-99mhr
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,158] {ssh_operator.py:80} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,204] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - SSH operator error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 167, in execute
    raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
AirflowException: SSH operator error: 
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,206] {__init__.py:1609} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,232] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-07-08 01:30:29,232] {configuration.py:287} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,314] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-07-08 01:30:29,313] {email.py:126} INFO - Sent an alert email to [u'bruno.pessanha@imc.com']
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,605] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     args.func(args)
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 523, in run
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 442, in _run
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     pool=args.pool,
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,606] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 167, in execute
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source     raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
[2019-07-08 01:30:29,608] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1321: Subtask check_source airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: 
[2019-07-08 01:30:32,260] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-07-08 01:30:32,259] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add new `ssh_conn_id` in Admin -> Connections. https://airflow.apache.org/howto/connection/index.html

Because of:

```
INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
```

Comment: Hi. That's the problem. It was added there and working find, but every time I restart its k8s deployment, I get this error. I've checked the postgres db and all the connections are persisted correctly.

Comment: are you running Airflow over k8s? I think it can be bug.

Comment: What is your database? hook configuration is stored in database. After restarted your k8s, does database still contain old data?

Comment: yes. After restarting the database, all the secret data is still there unchanged.